# using overlay2 on CentOS 7.4

Tags: centos, filesystems, storage, overlayfs

How do I install and enable the overlay2 storage driver on CentOS 7?

I have done many google searches on this and I see that version 7.4 is required.  So I typed the following commands to confirm that the intended server is running version 7.4 of CentOS:

```
[sudoUser@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)
[sudoUser@localhost ~]$ rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-4.1708.el7.centos.x86_64
[sudoUser@localhost ~]$
```

But there does not seem to be any `yum install overlay2` or `yum install overlayfs`.

> **So what specific steps are required in order to install and enable overlay2 on CentOS 7.4?**

Answer (score 0):

```
modprobe overlay;
lsmod | grep overlay
```

To make permanent:

```
echo "overlay" > /etc/modules-load.d/overlay.conf;
reboot
```

Comment: The question was on overlay2 not on overlay

Comment: @ShaiAlon overlay2 is a docker storage driver, not a kernel module. Docker overlay2 and overlay both use the OverlayFS kernel module, and this answer tells you how to enable it. The docker overlay2 storage driver requires a more complete overlayFS implementation, which is why overlay is also made available.